# docker nginx reverse proxy css and image rendering issue

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a environment where I have 2 tomcat containers are exposed say dev and test on ports 8080 and 8081 respectively. I am able to access the tomcat instances with host and port combinations as below.

```
http://<ip>:8080
http://<ip>:8081
```

Now I am trying to setup an nginx container as a proxy to send all /dev requests to dev(8080) container and all /test requests to test(8081) container.
Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  web1:
    image: "tomcat:latest"
    container_name: "web1"
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  web2:
    image: "tomcat:latest"
    container_name: "web2"
    ports:
    - "8081:8080"
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    container_name: "nginx"
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    volumes:
    - "./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
    #- "./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
```

Below is my nginx.conf file

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;

        proxy_redirect           off;
        proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header         Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header         Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header         Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header         X-Scheme $scheme;
        client_max_body_size     0;    

        location / {
        }

        location /dev {
            proxy_pass http://35.239.73.252:8080/;
        }
        location /test {
            proxy_pass http://35.239.73.252:8081/;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when i try to load my tomcat containers directly they work fine. But when they are accessed through nginx with uri paths /dev and /test the pages are broken and images and css are not loaded.

What could the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: I see below error from nginx logs

```
nginx    | 2019/07/14 04:13:57 [error] 6#6: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/tomcat.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 171.78.138.247, server: _, request: "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1", host: "35.239.73.252:8000", referrer: "http://machine1:8000/test"
```
My nginx container has been exposed on port 8000

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a closing "/" after both your location path and your target. Here's a working example from a project of mine:

```
    location ^~ /ll/ {
        proxy_pass http://werther:8080/;
    }
```